# Pyspark load multiple csv in subdirectories in S3

Tags: csv, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I have many CSV files in many subdirectories in S3. For example

```
s3://my-bucket/path/to/subdir-1/1.csv
s3://my-bucket/path/to/subdir-1/2.csv
s3://my-bucket/path/to/subdir-1/3.csv
s3://my-bucket/path/to/subdir-2/1.csv
s3://my-bucket/path/to/subdir-2/2.csv
s3://my-bucket/path/to/subdir-2/3.csv
```

I need to read them with `pyspark` in AWS Glue. I tried variations like

```
df = spark.read.csv('s3://my-bucket/path/to/', sep="|", header="true")
df = spark.read.csv('s3://my-bucket/path/to/*.csv', sep="|", header="true")
df = spark.read \
          .option("recursiveFileLookup","true") \
          .csv("s3://my-bucket/path/to/", sep="|", header="true")
```

I get `AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV...`. However, I downloaded the files and was able to read them locally with spark. So the data is clean. I guess the `read` command doesn't work with my S3's file structure? How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you have subdirectories ? Also is the schema of the Csv files in each sub directories the same?

Comment: you could just try * instead of  *.csv and that should work. something like df = spark.read.csv('s3://my-bucket/path/to/*)

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya The file structure is made by upstream jobs. So, yes as a last resort, I'll have to change upstream to reproduce the files. I I downloaded the files and I was able to read with spark locally. So the data is clean.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya I think your suggestion is identical to the first variation I listed.

Comment: Don't do schema inference against data on S3. CSV Schema inference means; "read in all .CSV files once just to work out the schemas". You waste time and money. Work out the schema off one file and set it explicitly.